# Spherical gradient texture on plane not working

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to find the most simple way to put a spherical gradient texture on a plane (square) so that the circle of the gradient and the plane are aligned center to center and the circle fits the plane.

I can do it with the gradient texture but the circle of the gradient just never fits the plane. I read somewhere that the center of the gradient will be where the origin of the geometry is, but I have the origin of the plane in its center, yet the gradient is always off. I could play with the mapping node settings and scale and translate until it more or less fits, but I just can't imagine I need to do it manually, that there isn't a more simple and exact way?
I'm using cycles render.

Using the node setup posted by LukeD in his answer, I do get the desired result starting from scratch, using the startup blend file. But with my project file, using the same node setup, the plane remains just black. Then I noticed a tiny little dot of a gradient circle in the middle of the plane, when rendered close up. It's very tiny and even pushing the colour ramp handles extreme to the edge just barely makes it bigger. I have my units setting on metric, with a scale of 0,01 because I work with centimeters. Changing the units to "none" and the scale to "1" did not seem to have any effect on the result. (see screenshot)

I added a mapping node with the "texture" tab clicked and a scale of x1000 to all 3 axes and this fixed the problem, giving the expected result (see screenshot)

So is this a bug? Why is a x1000 scale factor needed (not x100) to make up for a 0,01 scaling?

[image: gradient texture not working as expected]

[image: Scaling up with a Mapping node fixes the problem]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Connect Texture > Gradient Texture (spherical)* to *Diffuse color* node, as a vector choose *Object* and add *Color Ramp* to play with colors and color blends.

[image: gradient]

**Edit:**

For transparency you can choose Color Ramp as factor for Mix Shader.

[image: gradient_2]

**Edit 2:**

I have created scene with the same unit settings as yours and here is what we have:

Plane, scaled to 2x2m.

[image: gradient_3]

And this very same setup but with applied scale (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

[image: gradient_4]

**Edit 3:**

I have checked it in Blender 2.77a and 2.78 RC1 and it looks all the same. So my guess (as Blender docs doesn't cover much about *Texture Coordinates > Object*) it's not a bug but this is how those calculations works. Other textures behave the same. You can 'fix' texture scaling in *Texture tab* without setting *Mapping node* and calculations there are correct - *scale 100*.

[image: Gradient 5]

**Edit 4:**

Good catch with other dimensions. Now I'm totally stuned about it. 
But here is a method that is working with every dimension scale (applied or not). Don't ask me why it is working, but it is working :)

You need to change *Texture Coordinates* to *Generated* then in *Texture tab* change *Location* to *X > 5mm* and *Y > 5mm* (this is part that I don't know why 5mm is ok for 2, 20 and 200m, this was my lucky guess) and *Scale* to *0.5*.

[image: gradient_6]

Comment: I have tried the same node setup before. I tried it again, copying it from your image, in a clean, new .blend scene and it didn't seem to work. Then I noticed a tiny little dot of a gradient circle in the middle of the plane, when rendered close up. It's very tiny and even pushing the colour ramp handles extreme to the edge just barely makes it bigger. Now this is a mystery! I have made a screenshot but not sure how can I post it in a comment.

Comment: Check this blend file and tell me how it's working: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1928/ Tell me also which Blender version are you using and what GPU do you have, and maybe units used in project.

Comment: Thank you: works perfectly well with your .blend file on my computer. I have the same node setup and it doesn't work in my file. I have checked the units setup: you use none but when I changed to metric with a 0.01 scale, it still works. In my file I use metric with a 0.01 scale and it doesn't work even if I change over to "non". I use Blender 2.76 b , I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Comment: I just tried again, from scratch, using the startup blend file, and it works there too. Must be something interfering in the specific blend file that I use?

Comment: Could be some settings. Upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and I'll give it a look.

Comment: I have experimented some more and it turned out that using my blend file, adding a mapping node with a scale of x1000 to all 3 axes, fixes the problem and gives the expected results. I'll edit my question accordingly with new screenshots.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Can you reproduce the issue? Would you still like to see my blend file? Thanks

Comment: Check my Edit 2.

Comment: With the same unit settings, when I create a plane, it will be 2m x 2m by default, no scaling needed and no applying transformations. I put on it the texture with the same node setup as you and I get the tiny dot of a gradient, not the expected result.

Comment: Ok, upload this blend file of yours :)

Comment: Here it is: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1932" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1932/)

Comment: Ok, it's all in edit 3. Probably textures are by default set to certain scale and by changing it you need to change texture scale.

Comment: I see... So whatever scale I set in "units/scale" other than 1, I need to make up for it in the texture tab, rescaling textures back to normal, so they behave as expected, right? And this has to be done one by one with each texture in the scene I guess?

Comment: Only with Texture Coordinates > Object. With rest of modes everything is ok as they aren't based on object scaling rather then UV's, vertex and such.

Comment: Right, I understand. Thank you very much LukeD!

Comment: Of course! You certainly deserved both.

Comment: This really solves my problem and I'm happy, but look at this: if I create 3 planes 2x2m, 20x20m, 200x200m (none of them scaled and applied transforms) and put the same texture on them, the gradient circle will be the same size on all 3 planes! If it fits the 2x2 plane, it will be just a little dot on the 200x200 plane. Different size planes need different correction in the texture tab? Should not Texture Coordinates > Object make sure the texture fits the object regardless of it's size?

Comment: Check Edit 4. Citing Ozzy Osbourne - "Crazy, but that's how it goes" :)

Comment: Yes it works. I have seen people doing this before and was wondering why. Well they do it because this works and I'll just do the same. No questions :)

Comment: Personally I don't like 'dirty' methods, hacks and fakes but in this particular question (minding lack of information in docs) it's probably the true method ;)

Comment: This also solves issues I have had with other procedural textures like noise. I've always had problems to make the noise show up and then to control its size... same issue. A "clean" method would be nicer but having learned this method will save me lots of headache and time in the future. At least we have a way to control the texture.